# With Cookie does not exist on response factory Laravel

Tags: laravel

I am trying to return a cookie key value with my response from my laravel backend to my frontend but I get an error which says

```
Method Illuminate\Routing\ResponseFactory::withCookie does not exist.
```

Here is my controller.

```
public function login(UserLoginRequest $request)
{
    if(Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->get('email'), 'password' => $request->get('password'), 'role' => 'user'])){
        $user = Auth::user();
        $success['token'] =  $user->createToken('AppName')->accessToken;
        $success['user'] = new AppUser($user);
         return response()->WithCookie(cookie('token', $success['token'], $minute = 10))->json(['success' => $success], 200);
    }  else {
        return response()->json(['errors']);
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`response()` returns the Response Factory; it is not a Response itself. You have to call a method on the Response Factory to get a Response object, like when you call `json(...)` on it.

You need to call `withCookie` on the Response object, not the Response Factory:

```
return response()
    ->json(['success' => $success], 200)   // JsonResponse object
    ->withCookie(cookie('token', $success['token'], $minute = 10));
```

You are now calling `withCookie` on the JsonResponse object which is a Response object.

Comment: I get that. Makes a lot of sense. Solved my issue. Thank you.